# sudo eats up commands pasted via putty. Why?

Tags: sudo, putty, clipboard

When I paste multiple commands into putty window,
commands stop executing after first `sudo`.

## Why?

My clipboard (I'm careful to copy also newline after the 2nd command)

```
sudo -u smith echo aaaaaaaa ;

echo bbbbbbbb ;
```

Result:

```
$ sudo -u smith echo aaaaaaaa ;

echo bbbbbbbb ;

aaaaaaaa
$
```

It executes `echo aaaaaaaa` as expected, but 2nd command is not executed.

Setup: I connect from windows 10 via putty to red hat server, shell is bash.

---

#### debugging attempt

Seems `sudo` hijacks pasted input somehow. (`-n` option does not help)

```
# Given clipboard:
sleep 5s
echo bbbbbb

# Result is:
$ sleep 5s
$ echo bbbbbb # <-- this line gets onto screen AFTER sleep has finished
bbbbbb
```

But if sleeping is done with `sudo`

```
Given clipboard:
sudo -u smith sleep 5s
echo bbbbbb

# Result is:
$ sudo -u smith sleep 5s
echo bbbbbb # <-- this line gets onto screen BEFORE sleep has finished
```

Comment: Use an additional `\\` (backslash) at end of each of your lines, but the last line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer, use a backslash at end of each line, but the last line.

```
sudo -u smith sleep 5s;\
echo bbbbbb
```

This will work.

Comment: Thanks. This works. Any chance you have explanation on "why this happens"?

Your solution puts makes it identical to putting both commands on the same line `sudo -u smith sleep 5s; echo bbbbbb`, but why does this new line matters for `sudo` at all?

Comment: It's a built-in "comfort" function of `sudo`, otherwise you would have to enter 2 times your sudo password for a command like `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade`. I guess it's possible to disable this, but I don't recommend to do so.